# Clarifai cURL image recognition intergration

Tags: curl, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition, clarifai

I am trying to get tags from Clarifai image recognition using cURL and PHP.

On their site there is this user guide:
https://developer.clarifai.com/guide/#authentication

---

**QUESTION UPDATE**

I managed to get valid responce, and it looks like this:

```
    {
  "status": {
    "code": 10000,
    "description": "Ok"
  },
  "outputs": [
    {
      "id": "ea68cac87c304b28a8046557062f34a0",
      "status": {
        "code": 10000,
        "description": "Ok"
      },
      "created_at": "2016-11-22T16:50:25Z",
      "model": {
        "name": "general-v1.3",
        "id": "aaa03c23b3724a16a56b629203edc62c",
        "created_at": "2017-08-09T17:11:39Z",
        "app_id": null,
        "output_info": {
          "message": "Show output_info with: GET /models/{model_id}/output_info",
          "type": "concept"
        },
        "model_version": {
          "id": "aa9ca48295b37401f8af92ad1af0d91d",
          "created_at": "2016-07-13T01:19:12Z",
          "status": {
            "code": 21100,
            "description": "Model trained successfully"
          }
        }
      },
      "input": {
        "id": "ea68cac87c304b28a8046557062f34a0",
        "data": {
          "image": {
            "url": "https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg"
          }
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "concepts": [
          {
            "id": "ai_HLmqFqBf",
            "name": "train",
            "app_id": null,
            "value": 0.9989112
          },
          {
            "id": "ai_fvlBqXZR",
            "name": "railway",
            "app_id": null,
            "value": 0.9975532
          },
          {
            "id": "ai_VSVscs9k",
            "name": "terminal",
            "app_id": null,
            "value": 0.9230834
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I tried to foreach tags:

```
     $response = curl_exec($curl);

     $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
     $body = substr($response, $header_size);
     $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
     $rows = explode("\n", $header);

     $err = curl_error($curl);

     curl_close($curl);
     $resp = json_decode( $body, true );

     if ($err) {echo $err; } else {
         // foreach thought tags, and if tag value is above 93, than show/echo it
     }
```

But I am having trouble to foreach tags, I can't echo any tag, and I would like to show only tag name with value above for example 93.

Comment: looks like your request is invalid. any ideas why this might be the case? this is not a debugging service. show some own efforts

Comment: I have no idea why request is invalid, I am trying two days, with lots of effort. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST"
Authorization: Key f26b16808e2a440abb5f28b1c00b6nnn (no brackets)

And then

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{ \"inputs\": [   { \"data\": { \"image\": {          \"url\": \"https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg\" } } } ] }

It basically needs to match the format in the cURL column located here:
https://developer.clarifai.com/guide/predict#predict

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I managed to get valid responce, I updated my question, could you plese look at it again, maybe you can help me even more. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay here - already answered in the Clarifai community forum but here's the response so that SO sees it:

`$response = json_decode($body, TRUE);
 
for($i=0; $i < count($response['outputs'][0]['data']['concepts']); $i++) {
  if($response['outputs'][0]['data']['concepts'][$i]['value'] > 0.90) {
    echo "Tag: " . $response['outputs'][0]['data']['concepts'][$i]['name'] . ", Value: " . $response['outputs'][0]['data']['concepts'][$i]['value'] . "\n";
  }
}`